# How to create a list of all accessible objects in Pyramid / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: web-applications, sqlalchemy, security, pyramid

I have developed a small web application using the pyramid framework and just implemented the integrated security features. I have created a ressource object, let's call it `Page`, and I endowed it with an ACL so that every user can see and edit the pages for which he has the appropriate permissions. This all works fine.

My question is the following: What is the pyramid appropriate way to create a list of all pages the currently logged in user is allowed to see?

The application uses URLDispatch and SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pyramid-appropriate way". Just query your database for a "list of all pages the currently logged in user is allowed to see".

```
db.query(Page).filter_by(owner=user_id).
```

There are Pyramid [cookbook](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/auth/user_object.html) recipes for idiomatic ways of accessing the user and the database session via `request.user` and `request.db` that may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

you could post filter them if the acls aren't known to the database....

```
from pyramid.security import has_permission

def make_permission_filter(request, permission="view"):
    def f(r):
        if r and has_permission(permission, r, request):
            return r
        else:
            return None

(r for r in make_permission_filter(request, permission="view")(db.query(Page).filter_by(owner=user_id)) if r)
```

there are drawbacks of course but that is one way to do it.